# Image centered behind <div>?

Tags: javascript, image, html, border

I am working with a 500px by 400px "div" in javascript/html, and I wish to place a 750px by 600px image (made in photoshop) centered behind it as a border of sorts. Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As I understood it, you want the image to show around the smaller div. You can also remove the white bg of the inner to have it show through.

http://jsfiddle.net/XJLTG/2/

```
#wrap{
    width: 550px;
    padding: 100px;
    background: url(http://example.com/img.png);
}

#inner{
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background: white /*whatever you want*/;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is better then making him mess with position:relative / position:absolute for sure

Comment: Gotta give it up for Float for brilliantly fashioned code. Of course, I'm a code noob, so take that compliment with respect to that lol

Answer (score -1):

Have a container div with position:relative; that's the size of the image with the image as a background and place the smaller div absolutely on top of that (center it using top and left css properties). Should do the trick.

Cheers!